# USE MULTIPLE CONDITIONS IN MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

How to USE multiple conditions in SQL UPDATE  CASES?

```
COLUMN1      COLUMN2   COLUMN3
BG1         STANDARD
FOX1        STANDARD
BRB         STANDARD
NBC         STANDARD
FOX2        STANDARD
CNN3        STANDARD
GAM1        STANDARD
AI1         STANDARD
CQN3        STANDARD
GSM1        STANDARD
OFD1        STANDARD
REST         NONSTANDARD
WEST         NONSTANDARD
EAST         NONSTANDARD
```

I want to set   column3 = 1 where COLUMN 1 FALLS IN ANY OF THE FOLLOWING NAMES 
(BG1,FOX1,BRB,NBC, CNN3 , GAM1, AI1  ) AND WHEN COLUMN2 = STANDARD

and also  set column3  = -2 where column1 isnt in the following names ((BG1,FOX1,BRB,NBC, CNN3 , GAM1, AI1) and where Column2 = STANDARD.

I Wrote these

```
UPDATE SET COLUMN3 = 1  
WHERE (COLUMN2 = 'STANDARD' AND COLUMN1 = 'BG1' OR 'FOX1'OR 'BRB' OR 'NBC' OR 'CNN3' OR 'GAM1' OR 'AI1') 

UPDATE SET COLUMN3 = -2 
WHERE (COLUMN2 = 'STANDARD' AND COLUMN1 !='BG1' OR 'FOX1'OR 'BRB' OR 'NBC' OR 'CNN3' OR 'GAM1' OR 'AI1')
```

It isnt working. Any advice?

Comment: What field you want to update specifically?

Comment: Then take a look at the [`IN` operator](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in). Or put the parentheses in the correct positions, taking into account that [`AND` has higher precedence than `OR`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/operator-precedence.html), as in many/most (all?) other languages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's look at this one first:

```
UPDATE SET COLUMN3 = 1  
WHERE (COLUMN2 = 'STANDARD' AND COLUMN1 = 'BG1' OR 'FOX1'OR 'BRB' OR 'NBC' OR 'CNN3' OR 'GAM1' OR 'AI1')
```

In the latter part of your WHERE clause you have `OR 'FOX1'OR 'BRB' OR 'NBC' OR 'CNN3' OR 'GAM1' OR 'AI1'` This part always evaluates to False. You are not comparing these texts against any column. If you compared them to column1 without brakcets, it would almost always evaluate to true because there are plenty of matches where the column has one of those values. Check for yourself with

```
SELECT 1 and 0 and 0 or 1 or 0;
SELECT 1 and 'aa' or 'bbb'
```

First one always evaluates to true, second to false. Which is exactly what's happening in your query. Rewrite as

```
UPDATE SET COLUMN3 = 1  
WHERE (COLUMN2 = 'STANDARD' AND COLUMN1 = 'BG1') AND (column1 = 'FOX1' OR column1 = 'BRB' OR column1 = 'NBC' OR column1 = 'CNN3' OR column1 = 'GAM1' OR column1 = 'AI1')
```

Alternatively

```
UPDATE SET COLUMN3 = 1  
WHERE (COLUMN2 = 'STANDARD' AND COLUMN1 = 'BG1') AND column1 = IN ('FOX1','BRB','NBC','CNN3','GAM1','AI1')
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `in`:

```
UPDATE t
    SET COLUMN3 = 1  
   WHERE COLUMN2 = 'STANDARD' AND COLUMN1 IN ('BG1', 'FOX1', 'BRB', 'NBC', 'CNN3', 'GAM1', 'AI1') ;

UPDATE t
    SET COLUMN3 = -2 
    WHERE COLUMN2 = 'STANDARD' AND COLUMN1 NOT IN ('BG1', 'FOX1', 'BRB', 'NBC', 'CNN3', 'GAM1', 'AI1') ;
```

You can also express this as a single statement using `CASE`:

```
UPDATE t
    SET COLUMN3 = (CASE WHEN COLUMN1 IN ('BG1', 'FOX1', 'BRB', 'NBC', 'CNN3', 'GAM1', 'AI1') THEN 1  
                        ELSE -2
                   END)
   WHERE COLUMN2 = 'STANDARD' ;
```

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE TableName SET COLUMN3 = '1'
WHERE COLUMN2 = 'STANDARD'  AND column1 IN ('BG1','FOX1','BRB','NBC', 'CNN3' , 'GAM1', 'AI1')

UPDATE TableName SET COLUMN3 = '-3'
WHERE COLUMN2 = 'STANDARD'  AND column1 NOT IN ('BG1','FOX1','BRB','NBC', 'CNN3' , 'GAM1', 'AI1')